# Atualizar tabela de modo que um campo tenha um valor único

Tags: mysql, sql

Como posso atualizar um registro no MySQL de modo que quando alterar um campo desse registro todos os outros registros mudem para que esse campo tenha um valor único? por exemplo, tenho uma tabela chamada **jogadores** e um campo chamado **artiheiro**, que basicamente vai receber um valor booleano, só pra dizer que esse jogador é artilheiro ou não, e como não pode existir mais de um jogador artilheiro...  quando alterar algum registro para `artilheiro = 1` todos os outros registros automaticamente alterem para `artilheiro = 0`

Comment: Me parece uma solução estranha para o seu problema, porém se quiser resolver da forma que você mesmo sugeriu você pode criar uma `trigger` para isso.

Comment: a primeira ideia que me ocorreu foi: primeiro update o artilheiro atual para 0 e logo a seguir update o zé artilheiro para 1

Comment: Por que, Sorack? eu deveria "resetar" todos antes e atualizar o específico?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma `TRIGGER` que faça o que foi descrito:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_jogadores_ai AFTER UPDATE ON jogadores
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.artilheiro = 1) THEN
    UPDATE jogadores
       SET artilheiro = 0
     WHERE id <> NEW.id
       AND artilheiro = 1;
END;
```

Na `TRIGGER` citada acima você irá verificar se o registro foi alterado para `artilheiro = 1` e caso isso tenha ocorrido fará o `UPDATE` em todos os registros que não possuem o mesmo `id` e que tenham `artilheiro = 1` para `0`.